# Python included global variable is running whole function (file) - why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, include, global-variables

i need to include global variable from one file to another and its including the whole function... and i dont know why???

my source file create_repo.py:

```
def create_repository(repository_name):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic' +personal_access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent': 'Chrome'
            }

    payload = json.dumps({
        "project": "xxxxx",
        "name": repository_name
                        })



    global repository_id
    response = requests.request("POST", base_url, headers=headers, data=payload, 
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth("yyyy", personal_access_token))
    print(response.text)
    repository_id = response.text[6:44]
    print("ID of the new repository:" ,repository_id)
    



if __name__== "__main__":
    create_repository(sys.argv[1])
```

and second file in the same directory:

```
import create_repo
       print(create_repo.repository_id)
```

and this show me error: AttributeError: module 'create_repo' has no attribute 'repository_id'

and if is not in "main" functions it will include the whole file create_repo.py and is trying to create the repository one more time ...

i have tryed multiple settings like from create_repo import * or from create_repo import repository_id etc... nothing worked.

Comment: You can't get a variable that is defined in a function without *actually running the function*.

Comment: @Klára I think that you have to add `repository_id = ""` in the file create_repo.py outside of the function `create_repository()`. You choose the value to initialize `repository_id`.

Answer (score 0):

so i made a change (no definition inside of a function) as you told me and now i have this issue : :"1","innerException":null,"message":" (is trying to make the existing repository again in the policies file but it was already created in create_repo.py file)

create_repo.py

```
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Basic' +personal_access_token,
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'User-Agent': 'Chrome'
      }

 payload = json.dumps({
 "project": "xxxxx",
  "name": repository_name
                 })

 response = requests.request("POST", base_url, headers=headers, 
data=payload, auth=HTTPBasicAuth("yyyy", personal_access_token))
print(response.text)
global repository_id
repository_id = response.text[6:44]
print("ID of the new repository:" ,repository_id)
```

and the policies file

```
from create_repo import *
print(repository_id)
```

Comment: You DON'T have to remove the function `create_repository()` you have to add only the instruction `repository_id=""` outside of the function `create_repository()` in the file `create_repo.py`.

Comment: hi, it caused now that the variable repository_id is just "", but i need the repository id from create_repo script

Comment: In the policies file you have to call the function `create_repository()` and if in it it isn't error after its execution you can execute the instruction `print(repository_id)`

Comment: well but it caused that the repository will be created again... what i dont want to, i need to have it separate, is it any posibility?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code.

In the file `create_repo.py`:

```
# add the necessary import here
import ...

repository_id = ""

def create_repository(repository_name):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic' +personal_access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'User-Agent': 'Chrome'
            }

    payload = json.dumps({
        "project": "xxxxx",
        "name": repository_name
                        })



    global repository_id
    response = requests.request("POST", base_url, headers=headers, data=payload, 
    auth=HTTPBasicAuth("yyyy", personal_access_token))
    print(response.text)
    repository_id = response.text[6:44]
    print("ID of the new repository:" ,repository_id)
```

In the file `policies.py:`

```
import create_repo

if __name__== "__main__":
    create_repo.create_repository(sys.argv[1])
    print(create_repo.repository_id)
```

I have moved the `if __name__== "__main__":` from `create_repo.py` to `policies.py`.

Obviously you have to execute `policies.py` and not `create_repo.py`.